# Set public property within extended mysqli class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, extend

How to set value for public variable when *this* in another context and *self* wants only static props, which seems not be accessible after instantiation. There is a little extends for mysqli connection:

```
class db extends mysqli {
...
public static $bar;

private function __construct() {

    self::$bar = "test";
...

}

db::setOptions($db_options);
$link = db::getInstance();

echo $link->bar;


Notice: Undefined property: db::$bar in ... blah-blah-blah
```

Is there a right way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: bar is a static (or class) property, not an instance property, so you can't access it via `$link->bar` you must use `db::$bar` to get at class properties like this.

Comment: Thanks. So is there no way to make an instance property at all? _$this_ points to parent itself, _sefl_ to object itself.

Comment: self points to the class... not an instance, there is an important distinction there. The only way to be able to access it as an instance property is to remove the static designation from the property and then in all cases use $instanceVariable->bar when referencing it. Since this is a singleton, designating this as static isn't really doing you any favors.

Comment: Provided answer showing my take on how I think you mean for the class to be structured.

Comment: So is there a way to set value for public var in a class when _$this_ points not to the instance of class but to the parent which was extended by that class or like that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments designating this as a static property makes the property belong to the class as opposed to an instance of an object of the class.  To access class properties you have to use `classname::$propertyName` to access the property.

What you probably mean to do is:

```
class db extends mysqli {

  protected static $instance;
  public $bar;

  private function __construct() {
    $this->bar = "test";
  }

  public static function getInstance(){
    if (!isset(static::$instance)){
      static::$instance = new static();
    }
    return static::$instance;
  }
}

$link = db::getInstance();
echo $link->bar;
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the problem you are having I think you are just trying to provided global access to a shared db object that you can extend. If that is the case you may get better mileage from providing a wrapper for a mysqli instance instead of extending it. A simple way to do this is to create a wrapper object that proxies all undefined property access to an internally stored object.

```
 class db {
     protected $db;
     public $bar;
     protected static $instance;

     protected function __construct(){
         $this->db = new mysqli (....);
         $this->bar = "something";
     }

     public static function getInstance(){
         if(!isset(static::$instance)){
              static::$instance = new static();
         }
         return static::$instance();
     }

     // magic accessor proxy
     public function __get($property){
           return $this->db->$property;
     }

     // magic mutator proxy
     public function __set($property, $value){
           $this->db->$property = $value;
     }

     // magic call function
     public function __call($method, $args){
          return call_user_func_array(array($this->db, $method), $args);
     }

     public function __callStatic($method, $args){
          return call_user_func_array(array(static::getInstance(), $method), $args);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I cant use _this_ (I have tried it of course at first attempt) beause _this_ is mysqli connection. As I use it later: $res = $this->query($q)...

Comment: public $db;
    private function __construct() {
        $this->$db = $o['dbname']; 
 ... 
 Notice: Undefined variable: db in ... on line 301

Comment: should be $this->db not $this->$db;

Comment: And where is $o coming from.

Comment: BTW, above mentioned class came from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820421/extending-the-mysqli-class

Comment: I updated the db wrapper example to support static calls on the singleton class ... so you can now say `db::query($sql);`