# Need a way to add a function to query function of mysqli class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, overriding, extends

I am trying to implement a MySQL query execution time measurement on the existing site that is full of $db->query calls using the standart mysqli class

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port);
```

what I would like to do is to extend the query to do more each time it's called like to add a few actions. Would this work if I just extend the class?

```
class MyDB extends mysqli {
//The function to count the number of queries and their execution time
function query($query)
{
        //We increase the queries counter by 1
        global $nb_queries,$timer_queries;
        $nb_queries++;
        //Execute the query and time the execution time
        $beginning = timer();
        //Execute the query and save the result in a variable
        $req_return = mysql_query($query);
        //We add the query duration to the total
        $timer_queries += round(timer()-$beginning,6);
        return $req_return;
}
}
```

connect like so $db = new MyDB($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port);
 and then call $db->query(...my query...);

but this is not working for me... any hints on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why there is a need for **global** keyword ? Make those `$nb_queries,$timer_queries` as protected modifiers on your `mysqli` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending the MySQLi class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820421/extending-the-mysqli-class)

Comment: basically I shlould have called the query execution in this way $req_return = parent::query($query);

Comment: Shankar, I use those so that I can echo the variable in other places. Therefore I set them to 0 and then echo them in the page footer. See my working example below.

Answer (score 0):

Does your script give any errors?

Looks like you might be using the wrong function.

Is this line correct?

$req_return = **mysql_query**($query);

or should it rather be:

$req_return = **mysqli_query**($query);

Comment: mysqli_query($query) needs two parameters... I have resolved it anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working... it was too difficult to change all $db->query calls in the existing system so here is the working example of what I did:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user"; 
$pass = "pass"; 
$dbname = "test";
$port = "3306";

//------- new DB class to extend the functionality
$nb_queries = 0;
$timer_queries = 0;
function timer() {
    $time = explode(' ', microtime());
    return $time[0]+$time[1];
}

class MyDB extends mysqli {
  //The function to count the number of queries and their execution time
    function query($query)
    {
            //We increase the queries counter by 1
            global $nb_queries,$timer_queries;
            $nb_queries++;
            //Execute the query and time the execution time
            $beginning = timer();
            //Execute the query and save the result in a variable
            $req_return = parent::query($query);
            //We add the query duration to the total
            $timer_queries += round(timer()-$beginning,6);
            return $req_return;
    }
}

@ $db = new MyDB($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please let the IT know and try again later.';
    exit;
}
```

usage:

```
$var = $db->query("select * table");
```

and use this in your page HTML

```
<?php echo $nb_queries.' queries in '.$timer_queries.' seconds';?>
```